# Max repeated element Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

let's say i have some facts like this

```
something(a,b,[1,2,3,4]).
something(c,b,[2,3]).
something(e,b,[1,3]).
something(b,a,[1,2]).
something(c,a,[3,4]).
```

now i want to find which element is repeated mostly in list
in this case

```
max_repeated = 3.
```

thank you for your time and I hope someone will help me

Comment: lurker nothing I don't know where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
?- pred_key_count([K]>>(something(_,_,L),member(K,L)),T),aggregate(max(V,K),rb_in(K,V,T),max(V,K)).
K = 3,
...
```

with this definition:

```
:- meta_predicate pred_key_count(1,-).

pred_key_count(P,T) :-
    rb_empty(T),
    forall( call(P,K), %(something(_,_,L), member(K,L)),
        (   nb_rb_get_node(T,K,N)
        ->  nb_rb_node_value(N,C),
            D is C+1,
            nb_rb_set_node_value(N,D)
        ;   nb_rb_insert(T,K,1)
        )).
```